# How do I use WITH ROLLUP with two groups and not have it create two datasets?

Tags: sql

How do I use WITH ROLLUP with two groups and not have it create two datasets?

I need to include both name and ID and sort by ID. I was rolling up by name, but I can live without that.

```
SELECT SUM(salesFigures), productId, ISNULL(productName, ‘All’) AS ‘ProductName’
FROM MyTable

GROUP BY productName WITH ROLLUP

ORDER BY productId
```

Of course I get “Column ‘productId’is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.”

I tried adding productId to the group by rollup clause, but it doubled the result set, one set for productName and one set for productId. Of course I can't sum or otherwise aggregate productId.

Comment: "I can't sum or otherwise aggregate productId" - what about `MIN`? `AVG`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What is a "dataset" for you?

Comment: Sorry, It's MSSQL. Dataset = result set, I was thinking in VB, which is where this data is going. I tried Min and Avg but I still can't sort by without adding productId to the Rollup, which doubles the number of rows returned. I can do the sorting in VB but I didn't think I would have to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the `productId` values are the same you could apply a `MIN`, `MAX`, or `AVG` aggregation to that column:

```
SELECT SUM(salesFigures), 
       MIN(productId) productId , 
       ISNULL(productName, ‘All’) AS ‘ProductName’
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY productName WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY productId
```

Another option would be to do the rollup in a subquery and de-normalize the product IDs:

```
SELECT B.Sales, A.productID, ISNULL(A.productName, ‘All’) AS ‘ProductName’
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT productID, ProductName FROM MYTable
    ) A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(salesFigures) Sales, productname
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY productName WITH ROLLUP
    ) B
ON A.ProductName = B.ProductName
ORDER BY productId
```

Comment: Oh that's right, thanks.  Will accept as answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Huh, I still can't sort after adding MIN, MAX, and AVG, unless I put productId in the GROUP, such as: "GROUP BY productName, productId WITH ROLLUP" which still returns the doubled dataset... I'll have to try the subquery.